# Calculate total amount on every page

Tags: pdf, tcpdf

I am using TCPDF for generating pdf file in my account reports. I want to get the total sum of amount on every page.

[image: pdf_total]

I want to add these values and display at bottom of every page in TCPDF.

Anyone know how to achieve this?

Comment: Post some code please so as to get some idea about your query.

Comment: As *you* are generating those PDFs, you can easily add those values while you're adding them to the report, can you not?

Comment: But I dont know how many records would be placed in each page?